# How to create Master-Detail Grids in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm working on a custom page to visualize the relations between parent and child records by displaying the table data in a hierarchical order.

There are 2 data views in my BLC, which I'd like to use as the data source for two **PXGrids** to display the data in a master/detail format. When a record is selected in the master grid, all of the related child entries should be shown in the details grid.

How should I declare my 2 **PXGrids** in Aspx to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, if some BLC contains a **Categories** data view and a **Related Products** data view, you would specify the **Categories** view to be the data source for the master grid and the **Products** view to be the data source for the details grid. When a category is selected in the master grid, all products associated with that category will be displayed in the details grid from the Products data view.

```
public class ProductCategories : PXGraph<ProductCategories>
{
    #region Actions
    public PXSave<Category> Save;
    public PXCancel<Category> Cancel;
    #endregion

    #region Data Members
    public PXSelect<Category> Categories;

    public PXSelect<CategoryProduct,
        Where<CategoryProduct.categoryID, 
            Equal<Current<Category.categoryID>>>> CategoryProducts;
    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers
    protected virtual void Category_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CategoryProducts.Cache.AllowInsert = e.Row != null;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

As shown in the code snippet above, the detail view is referenced with the master view via a **Current** BQL operator. Also, notice **RowSelected** event handler defined for the **Category** DAC to disable **Insert** button on the details grid if there is not a single record in the master grid.

The next step is to configure master-detail **PXGrids** in Aspx:

- for the master grid set **SyncPosition** property to ***true***, then define the **AutoCallBack** and **OnChangeCommand** properties as follows to accordingly refresh the detail grid every time a different record or no record at all will be selected in the master grid:

  ```
  <px:PXGrid ID="masterGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" SkinID="Details"
      SyncPosition="True" Caption="Categories" CaptionVisible="True" Width="100%">
      <AutoCallBack Command="Refresh" Target="detailGrid" />
      <OnChangeCommand Command="Refresh" Target="detailGrid" />
      ...
  </px:PXGrid>
  ```
- for the detail grid it's only required to define a **Refresh** CallbackCommand to force the master grid to select data along with the details grid. By doing the framework will raise the previously defined **Category_RowSelected** event handler and disable **Insert** button on the details grid in cases when there is no record in the master grid:

  ```
  <px:PXGrid ID="detailGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" SkinID="Details"
      Caption="Products" CaptionVisible="True" Width="100%">
      <CallbackCommands>
          <Refresh SelectControlsIDs="masterGrid" />
      </CallbackCommands>
      ...
  </px:PXGrid>
  ```

For the sake of better user experience, it's recommended to place master-detail **PXGrids** within a **PXSplitContainer** as shown in the code snippet below:

```
<px:PXSplitContainer runat="server" ID="sp" PositionInPercent="true" SplitterPosition="50"
    SkinID="Horizontal" Orientation="Horizontal" Panel1MinSize="250" Panel2MinSize="250">
    <AutoSize Enabled="true" Container="Window" />
    <Template1>
        <px:PXGrid ID="masterGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" SkinID="Details"
            SyncPosition="True" Caption="Categories" CaptionVisible="True" Width="100%">
            <AutoCallBack Command="Refresh" Target="detailGrid" />
            <OnChangeCommand Command="Refresh" Target="detailGrid" />
            <Levels>
                <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Categories">
                    <Columns>
                        ...
                    </Columns>
                </px:PXGridLevel>
            </Levels>
            <AutoSize Enabled="True" />
        </px:PXGrid>
    </Template1>
    <Template2>
        <px:PXGrid ID="detailGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" SkinID="Details"
            Caption="Products" CaptionVisible="True" Width="100%">
            <CallbackCommands>
                <Refresh SelectControlsIDs="masterGrid" />
            </CallbackCommands>
            <Levels>
                <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="CategoryProducts">
                    <Columns>
                        ...
                    </Columns>
                </px:PXGridLevel>
            </Levels>
            <AutoSize Enabled="True" />
        </px:PXGrid>
    </Template2>
</px:PXSplitContainer>
```

And here is how master-details **PXGrids** should look and operate inside an Acumatica webpage:

[image]
[image]
[image]